# Placing randomly selected images into new folder

Tags: python, image, random, shutil, os.walk

I have a directory that contains a large amount of sub directories.

Within each of these subdirectories are different jpegs, pngs.

I want to:

Select X amount of random images from these subdirectories

Create a new folder and copy these selected random images inside.

Thanks to help received here already I can print out a random selection of images using `os.walk` and `random.choice`.

```
import os
import random
import shutil


files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Path/to/Directory"):
    for file in files:
        #all 
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
            files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))


#print images
#lets me count and print the amount of jpeg,jpg,pmg 
file_count = len(files_list)
print file_count

print files_list   
print(random.sample(files_list, 2))  #prints two random files from list
```

However, my issue is with actually selecting random images (not their names)

I have tried to create a variable `imagePath` that uses os.walk

```
#creates a variable imagePath that lets me access all img files in different folders
imagePath = os.walk("/Path/to/Directory")
```

and a new variable to randomly select a single image from `imagePath`

```
#create a variable that lets me choose random iamge from imagePath
randomImages = random.choice(os.listdir(imagePath))
```

and then created a new directory and used `shutil.copy` to move radnomally selected image into this new directory

```
#creates a new directory 
os.mkdir('testDirectory')

#moves the randomly selected image into new directory 
shutil.copy(randomImages, testDirectory)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawl.py", line 28, in <module>
    randomImages = random.choice(os.listdir(imagePath)) 
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, generator found
```

I have also tried

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Path/to/Directory", topdown=False):
    imagePath = ("/Path/to/Directory") #creates a variable that lets me access all img files in different folders
    randomImages = random.choice(os.listdir(imagePath)) 
    print randomImages
```

But this returns a random selection of sub directories (not images within) along with .ds store files.

Comment: I think the problem is in imagePath, `os.listdir(imagePath)`, `os.listdir` takes a string path to directory as an argument, imagePath is not, 
Try integrating this line of code, to iterate over the result and get dirs.
`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):`
os.walk() doc, [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm]

Comment: thanks @n0thing  I have tried this and updated my OP with new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, you want to move the files not make another copy I guess.

```
import os
import random
import shutil


files_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("<SOURCE_DIR>"):
    for file in files:
        #all 
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
            files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))


#print images
#lets me count and print the amount of jpeg,jpg,pmg 
file_count = len(files_list)
print file_count

# print files_list   
filesToCopy = random.sample(files_list, 2)  #prints two random files from list 

destPath = "<DESTINATION_DIR>"

# if destination dir does not exists, create it
if os.path.isdir(destPath) == False:
        os.makedirs(destPath)

# iteraate over all random files and move them
for file in filesToCopy:
    shutil.move(file, destPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to feed shutil.copy() a source and destination file path. It seems to me that you have a list of files already so you can just copy them.

```
import os
import random
import shutil


files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Path/to/Directory"):
    for file in files:
        #all 
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
            files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))


#print images
#lets me count and print the amount of jpeg,jpg,pmg 
file_count = len(files_list)
print file_count

print files_list   
selected_files = random.sample(files_list, 2))  #assign to a list

dest_path = "/path/to/new/folder/"
os.mkdir(dest_path)

for src_path in selected_files:
    shutil.copy(src_path, os.path.join(dest_path, os.path.basename(src_path)))
```